# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp' python3.10

Tags: python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp, python-3.10, modulenotfounderror

I've been trying to make a .exe file out of my code, but i'm facing this error:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp'**

I tried to uninstall and install again. I tried to start over the project, to make sure it wasnt get a different version of the package, but nothing seems to work.It just doesn't load or the lib to the compact version. It's been used in a virtual environment.

When i run the file in my IDE, it works just fine. I've read a couple of articles in the internet, but I still couldn't fix.

If anyone faced this before. I'd be gladly to get any help.

Python -version 3.10
aiohttp==3.8.1

The module to be imported just fine

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why. but when converting to exe, somehow it wasn't getting the lib path of my virtual enviroment.
So what I had to do was set manually the path where the packges were located.

Example:

pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --console **--paths** **"C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/ProjectName/venv/Lib/site-packages"**  "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/ProjectName/main.py"